# REGEX: how to match each string within double braces in an input string, if it occurs more than once?

Tags: regex, string, special-characters

Let me take an example to show clearly the issue;
say I want to match all alphabetic strings wrapped by double curly braces {{ }} which can contain curly braces as well. here is the expression i tried

```
/{{([A-Za-z {}()]+)}}/g
```

but when i give this input

```
"{{foo}} {{bar}}"
```

it matches `foo}} {{bar` and not `foo` `bar` as i wanted.

so my quetion is how  do i solve this ?  and is there a way to escape double braces in case i want to explicitly write them and not be considered by the regex ?

Comment: `/{{(.*?)}}/g` is enough.

Comment: waa! i wonder how and why this works,  and why mine doesnt

Comment: okay, I get it now, the `?` is the thing. Thanks!